# What happens to session if cookie time is set to zero?

Tags: php, cakephp

Suppose if cookies expire time is 0, then what will happen after executing code? Will all the session data be destroyed automatically? Will the user able to login into the website?

Comment: You should accept Lawrence's answer.

Answer (score 8):

[From the docs:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

> If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the
>   session (when the browser closes).

Comment: what if cookies are with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Your session will be active as long as your browser (tab) is open. When it's closed, session is terminated and you have to login again.